# Algorithm to generate all possible (unordered) assignments of one set to another

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, collections

Given:

1. A set of uniquely colored crayons (of size x).
2. A set of children.
3. All crayons must be assigned to the children.
4. A child may have anywhere from zero to x crayons.
5. Each crayon should end up with exactly 1 child. A crayon cannot be assigned to 2 or more children.

How do I go about finding all possible assignment combos?

For example:

```
class Crayon {
    String color;

    public Crayon(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return color;
    }
}


class Child {

    String name;
    Set<Crayon> crayons;

    public Child(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        crayons = new HashSet<Crayon>();
    }

    public void addCrayon(Crayon crayon) {
        crayons.add(crayon);
    }

    public Set<Crayon> getCrayons() {
        return crayons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child [name=" + name + ", crayons=" + crayons + "]";
    }
}

public class DistributeCrayons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Crayon> crayons = new HashSet<>();
        crayons.add(new Crayon("red"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("blue"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("green"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("orange"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("brown"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("yellow"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("purple"));

        Child bob = new Child("bob");
        Child amy = new Child("amy");
        Child tom = new Child("tom");

        for(??) {
            for(??) {
                ??
                    System.out.println(bob +" "+ amy +" "+ tom);
                ??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should output all possible assignment combos, for example:

Child [name=bob, crayons=[green, blue]] Child [name=amy, crayons=[brown, red]] Child [name=tom, crayons=[yellow, purple, orange]]

Child [name=bob, crayons=[]] Child [name=amy, crayons=[brown, red, blue]] Child [name=tom, crayons=[yellow, purple, orange, green]]

Child [name=bob, crayons=[red]] Child [name=amy, crayons=[brown, green, purple, orange]] Child [name=tom, crayons=[blue, yellow]]

etc.

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for the valuable feedback, and to גלעד ברקן for providing a working js solution. (sorry I'm unable to upvote or accept an answer due to reputation count).

I am now able to wrap my head around it, this is my version of the solution:

I converted the crayons and children to lists instead of sets. **For a list of 7 crayons (red,blue,green,orange,brown,yellow,purple), I aim to generate all assignments over the three children bob (id="b"), amy  (id="a") and tom (id="t") in the form of 7-character words.** For example: a word like "tbbbtat" means Tom gets the red, brown and purple crayons, bob gets the blue, green and orange crayons, and amy gets the yellow one.

```
public class DistributeCrayons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Crayon> crayons = new ArrayList<>();
        crayons.add(new Crayon("red"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("blue"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("green"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("orange"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("brown"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("yellow"));
        crayons.add(new Crayon("purple"));

        List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(new Child("b"));
        children.add(new Child("a"));
        children.add(new Child("t"));

        List<String> assignments = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < crayons.size(); i++)
            assignments = addCrayonCombos(assignments, children);

        System.out.println(assignments);

    }

    static List<String> addCrayonCombos(List<String> assignments, List<Child> children) {
        if(assignments == null) {
            assignments = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Child c: children)
                assignments.add(c.getId());
            return assignments;
        } else {
            List<String> updatedAssignments = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String assignment: assignments) {
                for(Child c: children)
                    //append next permutations for a new crayon to existing "words"
                    updatedAssignments.add(assignment+c.getId());
            }
            return updatedAssignments;
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the expected list of assignment words (2187 words to be exact), since we have 3 possibilities for each of the 7 crayons (i.e. 3^7 = 2187).

Comment: You could generate permutations of words consisting of `x` unique characters and `y-1` pipes. Say 1,2,3 for red, green, blue. Then 1|23| corresponds to a distribution. Make sure the characters are ordered and you get a distribution per permutation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is going to be ***way*** more complicated than a couple nested `for` loops.

I'm going to give you a problem statement and some pseudocode and maybe you can implement it from that.

You have two sets:

1. The crayon set.  We'll call this `C`.
2. The people set.  We'll call this `P`.

In your example,

```
C = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "brown"}
P = {"bob", "amy", "tom"}
```

So you'll want to implement a function `DistributeCrayons(Set<People> P, Set<Crayons> C)` that finds all the ways to distribute the crayons in `C` among the people in `P` where we can give zero or more crayons to each person in `P` for any given distribution.  And two distributions `A` and `B` are distinct if at least one person in `P` has a crayon in `A` that they didn't have in `B`

I'll give a recursive implementation since that will be the simplest to think about:

```
DistributeCrayons(Set<People> P, Set<Crayons> C):
    for subset C' of C:
        for person P' in P:
            assign C' to P'

            if (P - P') == {}:
                return assignments
            else:
                DistributeCrayons(C - C', P - P')
```

where:

`for subset C' of C`
Iterates through all possible subsets of `C` and assigns `C'` to one of them on a given iteration.

`for person P' in P:`
Just iterates through `P`--getting a single person on each iteration.

`assign C' to P'`
Assigns the set of crayons `C'` to person `P'` (meaning the person `P'` gets all the crayons in set `C'`.)

`{}`
Is the empty set.  So, the `if` statement: `if (P - P') == {}` just checks if `P'` is the only person in the set of people `P` passed to `DistributeCrayons(...)`.

**Note: I haven't actually dealt with assignments and how to code them.  It will be more complicated than the way I have shown in the pseudocode because assignments will have to be reset on each call to `DistributeCrayons(...)`**

<strike>**I'll keep thinking about this to see if I could come up with an actual code snippet to give you.**</strike>

**UPDATE: Looks like you solved it yourself.  Nice!**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. The solution that comes to mind combines both permutations and partitions. First, take each permutation of the list of crayons. There are well-known algorithms for permutations, and a search should turn up a quorum of them.

For each permutation of the list, partition the list into three parts, and assign the three children the crayons from each partition. This should generate every possible way of assigning the crayons to the children.

To partition your list of seven crayons into three parts, you'll divide it at two locations. The first will be anywhere from before element 0 in the list until after element 6, inclusive. The second division will be anywhere from the same position as the first division, up until the end of the list (after element 6), also inclusive. It's best to think of these breaks as occurring *between* two elements of the list.

The partitioning can be done with a nested loop.

There are 5,040 permutations and I believe there are 36 partitions of each permutation, so that should be 181,440 total ways of distributing the crayons if I'm not mistaken. I don't *think* there will be any duplicates with this approach but I haven't proven it.

Answer (score 0):

The children are a bit of a ruse. If we iterate over the crayons and assign them to a different box in turn, we can get all the ways to assign them. We can then label these boxes as we wish (or give them to the children in order).

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(cr, ch, x, comb=[], i=0){
  if (ch.length * x < cr.length)
    return [];
    
  if (i == cr.length)
    return [comb];
    
  let result = [];
  
  for (let j=0; j<ch.length; j++){
    let _comb = ch.map((_, idx) =>
      comb[idx] ? comb[idx].slice() : []);
    
    if (_comb[j].length == x)
      continue;

    _comb[j].push(cr[i]);
    
    result = result.concat((f(cr, ch, x, _comb, i + 1)));
  }

  return result;
}

var crayons = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "brown", "yellow"];

var children = ["bob", "amy", "tom"];

var str = "";

for (let comb of f(crayons, children, 3))
  str += JSON.stringify(comb) + "\n";

console.log(str);
```